# New user register, script auto create problems!

Tags: php, mysql

im currently trying to create a php script that when a new user register, a script (eg:wordpress,blog etc..) will install for them.

I'm currently got the code below for just single setup, **but how can i setup a form for multi user?** which only allowing them to input the username (subdomain) and password.

```
<?php
class scriptname_Config {

    public static $title = 'new_script_title';

    // Domain name and path where new script will installed in
    public static $domain = 'username.domain.com';
    public static $absolutePath = '/new_register_username/';

    // Settings for general mysql database
    public static $db = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'scriptname',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'prefix' => 'scriptname_'
    );

}

define( 'scriptname_BASE_URL',      'http://'.scriptname_Config::$domain.scriptname_Config::$absolutePath );
?>
```

Or any tutorial that will help is appreciate! Thanks!

Comment: I guess by subdomains you want something like, user1.site.com; user2.site.com; user3.site.com ?

Comment: thats correct, thanks for correcting

Answer (score 0):

I guess by subdomains you want something like, 
user1.wordpress.com; user2.wordpress.com; user3.wordpress.com ?

Well, actually creating subdomains is not really as complicated as it sounds

1, you need to configure your DNS Records to accept wild card entries. 
   this is a good read that might help. [wildcard-dns-and-sub-domains](http://ma.tt/2003/10/wildcard-dns-and-sub-domains/)

2, define / design your application to support it; 
   where you can filter every incoming request based on the url accessed, and take appropriate actions; display theme; or fetch data; etc.

you might also want to look at opensource, [wordpress-mu](http://mu.wordpress.org/) and [status.net](http://status.net/)
   both in PHP or the [Jaiku.com](http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/) written in Python on Google AppEngine.

3, configure your webserver appropriately, to accept anyname.mysite.com; and send it your app.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/introduction.html).

You can use it to automate the installation of software, setting up virtual hosts, users, etc.

Example [wordpress install via puppet manifest](http://github.com/simpsonjulian/puppet-wordpress)